# C program without header

Tags: c, linux, compilation, dynamic-linking

I write a "hello world" program in C:

```
void main()
{ printf("Hello World\n"); }
```

Note that I haven't included any header file.

The program compiles with warning as

```
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~$ gcc hello.c 
hello.c: In function ‘main’:
hello.c:2:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~$ ./a.out 
Hello World
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~$
```

How is this possible? How does the OS link a library without including any header?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler builds your source file with a reference to a function called `printf()`, *without* knowing what arguments it actually takes or what its return type is. The generated assembly contains a `push` of the address of the string `"Hello World"` in the static data area of your program, followed by a `call` to `printf`.

When linking your object file into an executable, the linker sees a reference to `printf` and supplies the C standard library function `printf()`. By *coincidence*, the argument you have passed (`const char*`) is compatible with the declaration of the real `printf()`, so it functions correctly. However, note that the `printf()` that your program implicitly declares has return type `int` (I think), which the standard `printf()` also has; but if they differed, and you were to assign the result of calling `printf()` to a variable, you would be in the land of undefined behaviour and you would likely get an incorrect value.

Long story short: `#include` the correct headers to get the correct declarations for functions you use, because this kind of implicit declaration is deprecated, because it is error-prone.

Answer (score 7):

The `printf` function is in the C library (`libc` in your case) which is linked implicitly (actually gcc has a printf builtin but it's outside the point).

Including the header doesn't bring in any functions for the linker, it simply informs the compiler about their declarations (i.e. "*what they look like*").

Obviously you should always include headers otherwise you force the compiler into making assumptions about what the functions look like.

Answer (score 1):

In C, if you use a standard library function, you **have to** include the standard header where the function is declared. For `printf` you have to include `stdio.h` header file.

In C89 (and GNU C89 which is the language by default on `gcc`), a function declaration can be sometimes omitted because there is a feature called implicit function declaration: when a function identifier `foo` is used and the function has not been declared, the implementation would use this declaration:

```
 /* foo is a function with an unspecified number of arguments */
extern int foo();
```

But this declaration is OK only for functions that return `int` with an unspecified but  **fixed** number of arguments. If the function accepts a variable number of arguments (like `printf`) such program would invoke an undefined behavior.

Here is what C89/C90 says:

> (C90, 6.7.1) "If a function that accepts a variable number of arguments is defined without a parameter type list that ends with the ellipsis notation, the behavior is undefined.

So `gcc` is kind enough to compile even in C89 and GNU C89: a compiler could refuse to compile.

Also note that

```
void main() { ... }
```

is not a valid definition for `main` (at least on *hosted implementations* which is probably your case).

If your main function doesn't take any argument use this valid definition:

```
int main(void) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The header usually<sup>1</sup> contains only function declarations, symbolic constants, and macro definitions; it doesn't usually include function definitions.

All `stdio.h` gives you is the prototype declaration for `printf`:

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...); // as of C99
```

The *implementation* of `printf` is in a separate library file that your code links against.

Your code "works" for two reasons:

1. Under C89 and earlier versions, if the compiler sees a function call
   before a declaration or definition of that function, it will assume
   that the function returns `int` and takes an unspecified number of
   parameters;
2. The implementation of `printf` returns an `int`, and you passed in
   an argument that just happens to be compatible with what the
   implementation of `printf` expects for the first argument.

And to echo what everyone else says, use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`; unless your compiler documentation *explicitly* lists `void main()` as a legal signature, using it will invoke undefined behavior (which means everything from your code running with no apparent issues to crashing on exit to failing to load completely).

---

1. I say "usually"; I've run across some headers that contained code, but those were usually written by people who didn't know what they were doing.  There may be very rare occasions where putting code in a header is justified, but as a rule it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

> hello.c:2:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’

To deal with this warning, you should include the header file (`stdio.h`). You're accidently using an old feature of C that has been deprecated since 1999.

Also, the fact that the link doesn't fail simply means that the standard C library is linked in by default. Whether or not you have included the relevant header is immaterial.

Comment: I do think that an implicit declaration `extern int printf();` is even not valid in C89 for a function like `printf` with a variable number of arguments. `gcc` is kind enough to compile in c89.