# C program is running without including Header files?

Tags: c, turbo-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C program without header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930641/c-program-without-header)

I have been studying C for a long time . but one thing that bothering me is that , today I made a C program and forget to include the stdio.h and conio.h header files I saved the file as kc.c ? when I compiled and run this .c file the output was as I was expecting to be.

but how can a C program could run without using the standard header file?

or I am not aware with the concepts that I am missing hear?

**EDIT:** the program

```
int main()
{
  int i=12,j=34;
  int *pa=&i,*pb=&j;
  printf("the value of i and j is %d %d respectively ",*pa,*pb);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

because I have used the printf() function of STDIO.H header here ,but without including it how can It got compiled and run successfully?

Comment: Assuming VS here, i.e., a C89 compiler?

Comment: @EdS.: ya I am using turbo C compilar

Comment: The compiler must be inherently aware of those functions (or the linking just happens to magically work out ok -- probably not the case for printf).  It is of course non-standard though, and I would expect most compilers to at least give you a warning even if it is aware of it.

Comment: @Corbin: you are forgetting the pre-standard behaviour of C, which old compilers like Turbo C still allow.  Those interpreted any function invocation of an undeclared function as declaring the function with an indeterminate argument list and returning an `int`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I actually thought it was standard that an int return would be assumed if an undeclared function were come across.  I would just expect a warning because the compiler knows the function declaration in this situation, and it knows a variadic function should definitely be declared.  (After all, if it knows how to correctly link printf without a declaration, it likely has some special knowledge, that it's not required, but chooses, to know of standard functions.)

Comment: Strictly, in C99 and C11 (the old standard and the current standard), that is not the behaviour; you have to declare functions before using them.  However, Turbo C is a pre-99 compiler, so it doesn't enforce that, and many other compilers default to the older, more relaxed rules.  Even C89 preferred you to declare functions properly, but it had to allow the older code to compile, so it inferred the `int somefunc();` declaration when it encountered `somefunc` in a context that could only make sense if it was a function.

Comment: You may find that Turbo C does indeed not issue a warning at *any* warning level; it is after all 20 years old, targets an obsolete 16-bit OS and allows code that is not even ANSI C 89 compliant.  There are few excuses for using this antique software when modern free compilers are available.

Comment: Worth noting: calling complex functions (e.g. functions taking 64-bit args, functions taking structure args, pointer args, etc.) without the appropriate function definition risk actually miscompiling the function call and resulting in program errors...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to make things work, but is under no obligation to do so.

You are supposed to declare all variable argument list functions before using them; not declaring `printf()` properly leads to undefined behaviour (and one valid undefined behaviour is to work as expected).

You should be getting warnings about the undeclared functions if you compile in C99 mode (but Turbo C probably doesn't have a C99 mode).

---

Nit-picking:

> [H]ow can a C program could run without using the standard header file?

All programs *run* without using any headers whatsoever.  However, most programs are *compiled* using the standard headers to declare the standard functions, and the better programs ensure that all functions are declared before they are used (or are defined as static functions before they are used).

C99 requires this, though many compilers will allow errant programs to compile.  However, the compilation should produce a diagnostic; the diagnostic may or may not lead to the compilation failing.  In practice, it usually doesn't cause the compilation to fail, but it could and with some compilers (GCC, for example) you can force the compiler's hand (e.g. with GCC's `-Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=old-style-definition` options).

Comment: In C99 functions do not have an implicit return type, so this should be an error in that case, not a warning.

Comment: You should get a diagnostic.  Whether the compiler continues depends on the compiler. GCC (for better or worse) with either `-std=c99` or `-std=c99 -pedantic` just issues a warning, not an error.

Comment: Interesting... perhaps I misunderstand the standard on this point.  I didn't think it would compile, off to read the standard...

Answer (score 2):

When the language standard being applied pre-dates ISO C99, C does not require a function to be declared or defined before it is referenced.

However when the compiler encounters such a function call, it simply assumes that the function returns an int and that it takes an indeterminate number and type of parameters.  This is called am implicit declaration.  If you later declare the function, or call it with a different number of parameters or incompatible parameters, you may get a warning in some compilers that the second call does not match declaration implied by the first, but the ISO C89 standard treats the function as variadic [like printf()] where any number and type of parameters are allowed.

Moreover if the actual return value is not an int, any return value accepted and processed may not make much sense one way or another.

It is bad form to rely on an implicit declaration, and most compilers would issue a warning.  If your compiler did not, you need to increase the warning level; those diagnostics are there to help improve your code quality.  If you simply ignored the warning (any warning for that matter), then you shouldn't!

In C++ the rules are tighter and failure to declare or define a function before referencing it is an error, since it is necessary to allow function overloading.

Comment: Well, actually... `int main() { bar("a", 1); bar(24); }` compiles (but obviously doesn't link) with no warnings or errors under `gcc -std=c89` (aka `gcc -ansi`). The implicit declaration is of the form `int bar()`, i.e. a function which takes *any number of arguments* and returns `int`.

Comment: @nneonneo: No warnings? I would habitually use use -Wall -Werror in gcc. You are correct about the implicit declaration being variadic and therefore any parameters are accepted in different calls.  However I recall at least one compiler behaving the way I suggested but perhaps with a warning rather than an error.  Nonetheless it is inaccurate and I shall remove it.

Comment: Yes, I use -Wall -Werror with my normal code. However, AFAIK, -Wall means "add warnings that the compiler thinks are good to warn about", not "warn me about stuff that breaks spec". Indeed, 3.2.2.2 of the ANSI C spec explicitly defines how implicit function definitions work (they are equivalent to `extern int func();` placed above the call site).

Comment: @nneonneo:  It was the "no warnings" I was picking up on not specifically that -Wall would warn about implicit declarations or lack of prototypes - I do not know one way or another.  An interesting point on this is that in C an empty parameter list such as `func()` is equivalent to `func(...)` whereas in C++ it means the same as `func(void)`.

Comment: I said 'no warnings' because without -Wall `gcc -ansi` doesn't give a warning. Try it!

Comment: @nneonneo: I don't doubt it; I made the point in my answer that the compiler should be set at a level at which it does.  I use `-Wall -Werror` in GCC and `W4 \Wx` in VC++ for example.

Answer (score 1):

A header file is nothing more than a listing of constants, preprocessor macros and *function prototypes*. The function prototypes tell C what arguments each function takes.

If the compiler sees a function being used without a corresponding prototype or function definition, it generates an *implicit declaration* of the form `int func()`. Since C functions are linked solely by name and not by function signature (as is the case with C++), the linker later locates the function definitions in the standard library.

Comment: Only in pre-standard or (sort of) in C89.  C99 doesn't formally allow that.

Comment: @Ed:  Fair point, worth noting, but academic in this case since the OP's compiler allowed it, it is *implicitly* not using C99 compilation.

Comment: @Clifford: Because it is woefully outdated.

Comment: Yeah; Turbo C is used in some higher education courses in India.  You see a rash of questions about Turbo C each year, starting in September, and continuing through to the spring (assuming you live in the Northern Hemisphere).  It is worrying that such an archaic compiler is used; it doesn't really give the help that beginners need.

Comment: @EdS.: His compiler is outdated, but even VC++2010 C compilation is C89 (save for a few new C99 header files).  Using C89 remains a valid and in some cases wise decision if the broadest portability or support of legacy systems is required for example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:  Every year this comes up, and students are told, yet nothing is done about the courseware!?

Comment: @Clifford: Visual Studio implements C89 because MS doesn't think it is important to update their C compiler (to the detriment of their users that want to write code in pure C).  It is a flaw in an otherwise good toolchain and they have stated they will *never* implement a more recent version of the standard.  VS is also woefully outdated in this regard.

Comment: @EdS. Probably not the place for this discussion, but Microsoft's *commercial* decision not to support C89 does not seem unreasonable to me, especially while C and C++ continue to diverge - making a C++ compiler that is also a C compiler requires additional work that was not required while C was *largely* a subset of C++.  I can't help thinking that the C ISO committee are simply trying to differentiate C from C++ to maintain its relevance rather than for any real need for a new standard.  C remains relevant largely because Linux is written in it; that is of course not a target for MS. IMO ;)

Comment: "*C remains relevant largely because Linux is written in it*" - Many would argue that C is a better language than C++ in many ways.  Many of them do not write code that ever touches a Linux machine.  As far as I know, VS is the *only* relevant C compiler which implements *none* of the C99 standard.  My point is only that the C89 standard is *23 years old* and we have had quite a while to implement C99 now.  Whatever the reason may be, any compiler which implements only C89 is outdated.