# What default libraries are taken while compiling C project with GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I have simple application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    printf( "hello");
    exit( 0 );
}
```

When I compile it with command

```
gcc -c count_words.c
```

I have warning:

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
     exit( 0 );
```

I was trying to find where `exit()` function is defined. And found that it is defined in `stdlib.h`. But it is not included in my project and no additional libs defined in compile command.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but looks like `gcc` takes some libs as default. What are these libs and is it possible to tell gcc not include them?

Why compiler is not happy regarding `exit(0)` assuming that it somehow includes `stdlib.h` as default?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8930641/3049655

Comment: You're mixing up including headers and linking to libraries. Those are two completely different things.

Comment: So, in which library exit(int) exists ? And my compile command not includes any libraries.

Comment: [libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: According to my understanding libc contains many binary files and headers. I assume they are compiled like object files. Does it means gcc is searching for required function in whole list of libc binaries?

Answer (score 8):

Let's take your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    printf("hello\n");
    exit(56);
}
```

Although we get a warning on compilation:

```
~$ gcc test.c -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     exit(56);
     ^
test.c:6:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
test.c:6:5: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘exit’
```

Anyway, I think you have tried to run it and make sure it works:

```
~$ ./test
hello
~$ echo $?
56
```

[@Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) was right when he said that:

> You're mixing up including headers and linking to libraries. Those are
>   two completely different things

The `C` compiler and linker are **totally** separate tools. Let's look on this. Actually, this program depends on the standard C library (as all programs if you didn't pass `-nostdlib` to compiler) and a couple of system libraries (like loader and vdso). You may see it with:

```
~$ ldd test
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff1b128000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f804389f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000557744537000)
```

These three library is a minimal set for any program. The `exit` function is defined in the standard library or `libc.so.6` in our case. Now let's look on the compilation process in verbose mode. You can achieve this by the passing `-v` or `--verbose` option to compiler:

```
gcc test.c -o test --verbose
```

If you will execute this, you will find lines like these:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/include
/usr/local/include
/usr/include
```

So, compile knows where to search header files for `stdlib` and it starts to search it to find declaration for non-local functions. Note that it searches only in header files which are included in your source code file. It can find `printf` declaration in the`stdio.h`, but can't locate declaration of the `exit`.

After this step, the compile starts to link your program with libraries:

```
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/collect2 ... -lc ...
```

Where `collect2` is gcc util which tries to link your program with `lc` which is standard C library. Note that the process consists from two steps: compilation and linking. That's why your program works.

Additionally, `gcc` supports `-M` option which will tell you about dependencies of the main file. So, if you will execute it, you will see the set of header files including `stdio.h`, but not `stdlib.h`:

```
$ gcc -M test.c
test.o: test.c /usr/include/stdc-predef.h /usr/include/stdio.h \
 /usr/include/features.h /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h \
 /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h \
 /usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/include/stddef.h \
 /usr/include/bits/types.h /usr/include/bits/typesizes.h \
 /usr/include/libio.h /usr/include/_G_config.h /usr/include/wchar.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/include/stdarg.h \
 /usr/include/bits/stdio_lim.h /usr/include/bits/sys_errlist.h
```

Or even better, try to pass `-E` option to `gcc`:

```
$ gcc -E test.c
```

and you will see result right after the first stage - preprocessing stage. I think it is the easiest way to understand why you are getting this warning.

Answer (score 1):

> assuming that it somehow includes stdlib.h as default?

It simply doesn't. That wouldn't be standards-compliant.

So, when you use `exit`, it has never been declared, so there's you implicit declaration upon usage. However, the fact to you implement `exit` nowhere else will only become a problem at the final linkage.

Now, GCC knows damn well that you are about to get into trouble, so it warns you.

Simply actually include stdlib.h and you should be fine.

Comment: Also note that the implicit function declaration isn't valid since C99 IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

The "library" in question is gcc/builtins.def from the gcc source tree.

That's not just a header file though, and it does not provide declarations for you to use. But it has proper prototypes to check yours against.

Calling undeclared exit() results in implicit declaration like this:

```
int exit(int);
```

Search "c implicit declarations" for the gory details. In this case however GCC has its own prototype for exit() from builtins.def:

```
void exit(int) __attribute__((nothrow,noreturn));
```

These declarations do not match, and that's what you are being warned about.

Answer (score -5):

Your code works with warning not with error. If you add

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

then no warning anymore ;)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and just tells the stuff the OP already knows.