# What libc and can I omit it's includes in my project?

Tags: c, gcc

I have simple program without includes that compiles with some warnings:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello");
    exit(0);
}
```

---

**Compile:**

```
gcc hello.c

Warning:
In function ‘main’:
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
     printf("hello");
     ^
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
     exit( 0 );
     ^
```

compilation command is very simple and not contains information regarding include library files that contains `printf` and `exit`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but looks that gcc links my project to these libraries by default. That points me to thinking that include files of libc libraries is not required?

Correct me once again. I got warnings because GCC somehow knows some basic functions of libc and these functions has different params. But since GCC checks all libc it founds correct function anyway.

What is libc at all. Is it some standard set of binary object and header files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What default libraries are taken while compiling C project with GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693100/what-default-libraries-are-taken-while-compiling-c-project-with-gcc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> looks that gcc links my project to these libraries by default. That points me to thinking that include files of libc libraries is not required?

- Includes and linking are not related that way. The includes contain function prototypes that instruct the *compiler* about the return value type and parameters of a given function. When a function call happens, and there is no prototype for it yet the compiler assumes it returns `int` and that may lead to undefined behavior.

  The program will be linked to the standard libraries and function definitions will be available, but since the program was compiled with the assumption that these functions all return `int` there can be runtime errors related to this, which cannot be predicted since the behavior is *undefined*.

> I got warnings because GCC somehow knows some basic functions of libc and these functions has different params. But since GCC checks all libc it founds correct function anyway.

- No, it has nothing to do with *gcc* knowing anything but the opposite, it has to do with *gcc* not knowing how to call these functions.

> What is libc at all. Is it some standard set of binary object and header files?

- *libc* is a binary file *libc.so.6* in current *glibc* and it's the runtime library with all the symbols needed by a standard [c](/questions/tagged/c) program, it does not include *math.h* funcions for example (*that is libm.so.6*).

  You still need header files in your [c](/questions/tagged/c) programs for the reasons explained above, or at least declarations of the standard functions you use. These declaration are called prototypes and are **required** by the compiler in order to **correctly** compile your code.

**NOTE**: Always compile with at least `-Wall -Werror`, like this

```
gcc -Wall -Werror hello.c
```

Comment: Please disregard the advice about always using -Werror.

Comment: NO: headers are something, *libc.so.6* is something else. Please read carefuly. Headers only provide constants, function prototypes and structure definitions.

Comment: @FUZxxl can you explain why? If you are an expert it's ok, suppose that you do something intentionally that would trigger a warning. If you are not an expert, what is wrong with it? That it will highlight some mistakes that you didn't know were mistakes?

Comment: Because it's stupid advise for a number of reasons too long to list here.

Comment: @FUZxxl I need one only, not the whole list. And *stupid* is a strong word so please support it with criterion.

Comment: Yes, I know that headers provide function definition, but function executable code defined in stdio.h and stdlib.h are placed in libc.so.6?

Comment: @vico Funcion excutable code *of the functions **declared** in stdio.h and stdlib.h*.

Comment: Function executable code declared in stdio.h and stdlib.h are placed in libc.so.6. But why do I need so many header files then? Why not to create avthing_from_libc.h ?